# Oracle and Sql developer Connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How do I find out the SID of my Oracle Database. I have Oracle 11g installed in my system, and i want to make a connection between SQL developer and oracle. But when I test the connection using the default SID ie xe it gives me an error of ORA-12505.

Comment: Did you install the express edition?  Or did you install a different edition of the database?  The express edition will always have a SID of `XE`.

Answer (score 6):

If you can connect to the database using sqlplus, just show the SID / instance name by doing;

```
show parameter instance_name
```

or alternately

```
select instance_name from v$instance;
```

Comment: Interesting select. I always do this by looking `TNSNAMES.ORA`, but this seems easier :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer Default connection for oracle 11g:

Go to connection > New Connection

```
Connection Name =  HR or use any other name
User name = hr
Password = Your Password (This is the password that you selected during the installation of the of Oracle 11g)
```

Check the "Save" option

```
role: default
port 1521
SID : orcl
```

If you want to create the SYSDBA Account: (Administrator account)

```
Connection Name =  admin ORCL or use any other name
User name = sys
```

`Password = Your Password` (This is the password that you selected during the installation of the of Oracle 11g)

```
role: sysdba (from the drop down)
port 1521
SID : orcl
```

TEST and Save Connect

Just in case if your HR account is locked because you have connected multiple number of times than you can fix this by logging into your SYS DBA account.

In the objects list on your list go to the OTHER USERS.

GO to HR Account > Right Click

`EDIT USER`

Choose the password you want and uncheck The account locked and the Password Expired options if they are checked.